# Как быстро перелить данные из InputStream в OutputStream?

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

Задача: нужно быстро перелить данные из `InputStream` в `OutputStream` без затрат дополнительной памяти.

Конкретного решения не нашел сам, либо приходится выделять массив байт по размеру потока (получается быстро, но жрет память), либо побайтово читать/писать (получается без накладных расходов памяти практически, но медленно).

Мимоходом предложили использовать либо каналы, либо трубы, но как это сделать правильно - понять не могу. Прошу Вашей помощи.

Сейчас имеется один из вариантов (медленный но не прожорливый):

`if (inputStream != null && inputStream.available() > 0) {
                int b;
                while ((b = inputStream.read()) > -1) {
                    outputStream.write(b);
                }
            }
            outputStream.flush();`

Вторым вариантом было не использовать `InputStream` вообще (но сейчас появилась острая необходимость в некоторых случаях читать напрямую из файла, а не из потока), пересылая массив байт, и писать в os его целиком.

Разница в скорости существенная, потоки могут быть длиной 100кБ и больше.

Заранее благодарен за ответы!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну выделять буфер по размер потока наверное не нужно, все равно придется копировать из одного потока в другой, все-равно придется как-то буфферизировать (главное оптимально выбрать размер буфера)

Вот Apache IOUtils (исходные коды), посмотрите, может найдете, что хорошего
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.java

Comment: Там везде копирование через буфер фиксированной длины. Я об этом думал, но решил применять в последнем случае...

Вот тут: [Best way to Pipe InputStream to OutputStream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715979/best-way-to-pipe-inputstream-to-outputstream), есть сравнение нескольких вариантов копирования, но, блин, в каждом варианте нахожу минусы...

Буду дальше рыть, но хотелось бы ещё послушать мнений.

Comment: ну смотрите, буфера не избежать (он будет фигурировать в любом случае), лично на моей машине шустрее всего работает через буфер в 4 килобайта.
"хотелось бы ещё послушать уважаемых программистов." уж обидел, так обидел..вообще то я senior developer, ну это так ни пиара ради  ;-)

Comment: Извините, словами "уважаемых программистов" я не хотел обидеть вас. Они не в том смысле, что вы программист не уважаемый, а обобщенно, этикета ради. Приношу свои извинения.

Да, сейчас как раз экспериментирую с размером 4096.

Comment: да я шутю)..просто сам когда-то с этим боролся;-)

Comment: IMHO если [еще и читать](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte[]%29) методом

    public int read(byte[] b)

в массив кратного PAGESIZE размера, то это будет хорошо.

Comment: Не нашел с наскока размер PAGESIZE... Можете подробнее прокомментировать его размер, и чем это хорошо?

Comment: Обычно PAGESIZE 4К. Ряд функций I/O внутри OS "хорошо заточены" под манипулирование областями памяти кратного PAGESIZE размера. 

Как в этом языке управления *кофеварками и пылесосами* (т.е. Java) стандартно выяснит размер PAGASIZE - не знаю. 

В линуксе можно воспользоваться выводом утилиты `getconf PAGESIZE`, но на практике, изнутри программы, вряд ли стоит этим заниматься.

Просто делайте буфера размером 4096, 8192 ...

Comment: "кофеварками и пылесосами", ну уж не так...это была изначальная идея, сейчас не верное выражение)
Там копирование идет нативным способом, т.е. как в системе так и джава, именно поэтому, отвечая, я сослался, что на моей машине, хотя 4к справедливо в большинстве случаев(x86), на моей памяти только* в sparc архитектуре 8к 
* это не значит, что "только", просто на моей памяти, никогда с ними не работал=)

Comment: @JEcho, сам-то язык неплохой, но сейчас (да уже, пожалуй, давно) Java втыкают во все, что можно. 

Только вот серьезные вещи на ней как-то (чуть нагрузка зашкалит) плохо шевелятся.  

А скоро  все будем еще и с hadoopm-ом (там сплошная Java) в облаках (это нынче очень модно у заказчиков) маяться.

Comment: А не могли бы вы не насаждать свои религии тут? Это я про "пылесосы и кофеварки и нагрузки". Продолжайте жить своим Си, а у джавы другие плюсы. Лично мне как минимум необходима кроссплатформенность. Да и синтаксис у джавы и шарпа обожаю.

За подсказки спасибо, есть идея как получать размер страницы, чуть позже на работе проверю и отпишусь.

Comment: эм..она от архитектуры зависит, в большинстве своем 4к, зачем ее получать? динамически она не меняется, сделайте настройку и делов то. 
Не холивара ради, я сам java'ист но, надо признать оперативку жрет она реально как пылесос

Comment: @Евгений Карпов, боюсь с кроссплатформенностью Вас слегка обманули. 

В большей степени (я имею в виду не HelloWorld) кроссплатформенность  это свойство задачи, а не языка реализации (к сожалению).

Реальность же такова, что представление компиляции в код VM и ее переносимость в качестве "write once run anywhere" это морковка перед носом у софтверных корпораций. 

Однако, хотя это может показаться странным, такое положение дел всех устраивает.

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите в сторону `PipedInputStream` и `PipedOutputStream` (pipe == труба).

Если грубо, то работает так:

> OutputStream -> PipedOutputStream -> PipedInputStream -> InputStream

Пример использования [здесь](http://www.certpal.com/blogs/2010/11/using-a-pipedinputstream-and-pipedoutputstream/)

Comment: хм...а вы сами то использовали их?;-) Они немного не для того)
Java:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html

Особенно прочтите фразу:
Attempting to use both objects from a single thread is not recommended, as it may deadlock the thread

Вы точно уверены, что стоит пробовать для копирования байт? ;-)

Comment: Ну а кто говорит, что надо в одном потоке использовать то?

Comment: ну в общем, явно не для этой задачи.
эта хреновина нужна больше для совокупления потоков, для потококвого обмена данными. Тут конкретная задача скопировать из входного потока, в выходной.